# How to get google search result links with selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the link (ideally url, title and description too) of each search result (no sitelinks, videos, sub-elements etc.) but without success due to the dynamic nature of google's page elements and attributes.

Here is the closest I managed to get:

```
driver.get(https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium);

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.id("rso")).findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='g']"));

for(WebElement element: elements){
   System.out.println(element.getText()); //getText() is used here for demonstration purposes                
}
```

I assume that key part is the xpath syntax thus feel free to post solutions from other programming languages. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add explicit wait before search elements on the page because as you can see the browser didn’t catch to load all of the elements. Example, it decreases waiting if the element is visible

```
WebElement explicitWait = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("element-locator-id")));
```